# Quota exceeded in localstorage firefox

Tags: firefox, local-storage, quota

We are facing a weird issue in Firefox(84.0.1) localStorage setItem method in all subdomains belonging to main domain throwing ***quota limit exceeded***. Tried of clearing data from **Manage data** as well as **Clear Storage** in `about:preferences`. But still issues persists. Any suggestions on how to proceed?